# Pl sql convert national characters to unicode

Tags: unicode, plsql

I try to convert Danish national characters to unicode. Is there function in plsql or parameter to plsql function which can help me ? I try this `select convert ('Æ, æ:,Ø, ø:,Å, å:','AL32UTF8') from dual;` but it doesnt help. As a workaround I used in my code something like that

```
w_temp := replace('Æ, æ:,Ø, ø:,Å, å:','å','\u00E5');
w_temp := replace(w_temp,'Å','\u00C5');
w_temp := replace(w_temp,'æ','\u00E6');
w_temp := replace(w_temp,'Æ','\u00C6');
w_temp := replace(w_temp,'ø','\u00F8');
w_temp := replace(w_temp,'Ø','\u00D8');
```

but this method is like a monkey job. My code is not prepared for any other national characters - have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The CONVERT() function can be used as follows `CONVERT('fioajfiohawiofh',<ORIGIN_CHARSET>,<DESTINATION_CHARSET>)`.

I don't know your charset, but you can try finding useful one using this SELECT:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT('Æ, æ:,Ø, ø:,Å, å:',cs.value,'UTF8') AS conv
  ,cs.value
  ,cs.isdeprecated
FROM
  V$NLS_VALID_VALUES cs
WHERE
  cs.parameter = 'CHARACTERSET'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the big picture is, but assuming that you currently have your data in a database with a single character set that supports your diacritics, I would rather use a completely different approach:

- export the needed data your database and the existing character set
- recreate the database with a unicode character set
- (very likely) change te definition and install all database objects with CHAR instead of BYTE semantics
- import all the data into the new database

Clearly there is a lot of details to sort out, but having Oracle to properly convert the character sets during import, seems to be only reasonanble way to go.